# Converting Sql query to Laravel 8 Query Showing error

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-8

Here is my sql query

```
select name, case
WHEN iso2 = 'DE' THEN 'Germany' 
WHEN iso2 = 'CH' THEN 'Switzerland' 
ELSE 'India' End
from cities
```

My Laravel 8 query

```
DB::table('cities')->select('name as lang_name', 'iso2', DB::raw('(CASE WHEN iso2 = "DE" THEN "Germany" WHEN iso2 = "CH" THEN "Switzerland" ELSE "India" END) AS codeCity'))->get();
```

Showing error
column: 7 ERROR: column "DE" does not exist LINE 1:

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('cities')->select('name as lang_name', DB::raw('(CASE WHEN iso2 = "DE" THEN "Germany" WHEN iso2 = "CH" THEN "Switzerland" ELSE "India" END) AS codeCity)')->get();
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from double quotes to single quotes. E.g. in postgresql double quotes is used to identify columns, while singel quotes are used for values. That explanation would explain your error.

```php
DB::table('cities')->select('name as lang_name', 'iso2', DB::raw("(CASE WHEN iso2 = 'DE' THEN 'Germany' WHEN iso2 = 'CH' THEN 'Switzerland' ELSE 'India' END) AS codeCity"))->get();
```

Comment: /*$c_list = DB::table('cities')
             ->select('id as city_id', 'name as lang_name', 'ascii_name as city_name', 'iso2', DB::raw("(CASE WHEN iso2 = 'DE' THEN 'Germany' WHEN iso2 = 'CH' THEN 'Switzerland' ELSE 'India' END) AS codeCity"))
             ->whereIn('iso2', array('DE', 'IN', 'FR', 'TA', 'CH'))
             ->orderBy('codeCity','asc')
             ->orderBy('city_name','asc')
             ->get(); */ Showing error "olumn "codeCity" does not exist LINE 1"